# Umbraco 10 connection string in different appsettings file results to site not working

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables, umbraco

I have a current umbraco version 10 site that works properly using appsettings.json but when I tried to implement appsettings.Staging.json in my staging server, when I access the site it prompts me an upgrade message.

I already set the aspnetcore_environment as Staging. but everytime I put the connection string back to appsettings.json and redeploy the dlls and exe, it works fine. Am I missing something on deployment or any umbraco specific configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permission issue. I have seen similar problems with my Umbraco v10 website when my umbraco app couldn't connect to the umbraco database due to some Azure firewall IP restrictions.

If you are running your Umbraco website on Azure, make sure your database's firewall is allowing your Umbraco website to reach it.

Also make sure that your Umbraco website's Web App's ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to Staging.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmmm, but the site on the same staging server works fine when it uses appsettings.json.

Comment: As your next step, try updating your staging config to use the same connection string as the appsettings.json's connection string, and see if you see any problems. If you do, then this could be due to some of your web app configuration settings, too. See that I have added another screenshot.

Alternatively, you can update your appsettings.json to use your staging connection string to see if there is any problem. If there is a problem, check the permissions and your configuration.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm pretty sure that the app is able to access the database since I encountered an error first pertaining to the apppool not having access to the database (resulting to the page displaying Install Umbraco prompt) then after I fixed that it gave a new issue which is the Upgrade umbraco message. I really can't figure out what's the problem. :D

Comment: What do you see in yourUmbracoWebsite\umbraco\Logs? Any logs to help resolve this problem? If possible, what happens when you restore your staging database from your the one that is working and try again? Also copying DLLs and exes etc doesn't sound correct for modern app deployments. Shouldn't you use some sort of pipeline to build and deploy your code?

Comment: Did you manage to check any of my recommendations? If my answer has helped you, please remember to check it as the correct answer or upvote it.